# Как получить текущий счетчик в bytes.Buffer

Tags: golang

Как получить текущий счетчик в bytes.Buffer. Допустим я прочитал часть байтов из внутреннего массива, как мне получить текущий индекс.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно вас понял, то поможет функция **Len** пакета **bytes**, которая возвращает количество непрочитанных байт в буфере.

```
func (b *Buffer) Len() int
```

Пример использования [play](https://play.golang.org/p/9UKWcXCh67)

```
package main

import (
 "fmt"
 "bytes"
)

func main() {
    var b bytes.Buffer
    b.Write([]byte("123456789"))
    fmt.Printf("len = %d\n", b.Len())

    r := make([]byte, 5)
    b.Read(r)
    fmt.Printf("len = %d\n", b.Len())
}
```

на выходе будет

```
len = 9
len = 4
```

после операции Write количество непрочитанных байт будет 9, после чтения пяти байт количество непрочитанных байт будет 4.

Comment: Да спасибо, почему то я думал что это указывает на количество байт во внутреннем массиве :)